# How to display content in iframe without Master Page

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe, master-pages

I have a iframe where it get and display of a page.

However if I display the page directly it may contain the header and footer from Master Page.

My question is can I display only the content of the page without the Master Page in iframe?

Please give suggestions and advises. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably pass a parameter into the page (through the querystring for example), which, when set, switches the masterpage to one that is effectively blank (since your page wont work without a masterpage).

So something like this in the Page_PreInit method

```
if (Request.QueryString["iframe"] == "true")
  MasterPageFile = blankMasterPageFile;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the master page property of the page within the iframe.

Comment: what if the page by default is already with master page? please help